# One SCM poll for multiple jobs to improve performance

Tags: jenkins, version-control

Is it possible to have Jenkins retrieve the code from SCM (Subversion in my case) periodically and all the jobs using this updated code instead of re-polling themselves every time they run ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve it:

Lets say you have 4 jobs: A,B,C,D.

Job A's configuration:

- `Source Code Management` configured with SVN repo details.
- `Build Triggers` set as `Poll SCM`.
- `Post-build Actions` configured to build jobs B,C,D.

Jobs B,C,D configuration:

- `Source Code Management` set as `None`.
- No `Build Triggers` set.
- Code from job A's workspace is used in the build steps.

Here job A periodically polls SCM for changes. When changes are detected, it pulls latest code from SCM and builds. Post build, it triggers jobs B,C,D.
Since jobs B,C,D are configured to use code from job A's workspace, they use the same code that was recently pulled by job A.

Comment: Thank you Arun. Does this mean that jobs B, C and D don't need any special config to "know" where the code is? Is it a common property set on Jenkins?

Comment: Jobs B,C,D do not need to know about where the code is. This is because we configure these jobs to use job A's code from job A's workspace. This can be achieved via a copy command in the Execute Shell build step. In jobs B,C,D you can add a build step to copy code from job A's workspace into the current job's workspace.

Comment: Thanks Arun, can do it via Copy Artifact plugin

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if jenkins has such a build in feature. But even if it has, I think the polling from jenkins side is always just the second best solution. Better try to notify jenkins about SCM changes and let jenkins decide which jobs to build.
You just have to call the "notifyCommit" URL of jenkins. See https://plugins.jenkins.io/subversion/ for details.